# Time Complexity of using list.extend vs explicitly using 2 loops

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, memory, time-complexity

So basically in my  problem I have a dictionary/map of number say hm1

```
hm1={1:2, 2:1,4:1}
```

where the values of the map i.e hm1[1]=2 is the frequency.

I am trying to create a list based on these frequences in the map.
I wrote 2 codes for doing so.

```
for idx,num in enumerate(hm3):
        for i in range(hm3[num]):
            l.append(num)
```

l=[] at the start so it's simply an empty list.

and code 2:

```
for n in hm3:
  l.extend( [n]*hm3[n])
```

It seems that the *code 2* is faster than Code1 after running it HOWEVER,
what is the underlying time complexity of the `list.extend([n])*hm3[n]` operations?

I know it's `O(N)' for the outer loop but want to know how does .extend work and thus, it's time complexity.

Thanks

Comment: the complexities are the same. at a guess: `x*[n]` creates a list at C-speed knowing the size of the list from the start (therefore there is no need for multiple memory allocations).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist what do you mean by no multiple memory allocations in this case? As for the  *n (you are saying it's implemented in C underneath?)

Comment: (i am just guessing!) in some programming languages lists have a capacity (i,e. the maximal space allocated at the moment). if this capacity is exceeded, a list with more capacity needs to be allocated & the elements that are so far in the list need to be copied. when constructing a new list you may give a "size hint" that prevents such allocations.

Comment: and yes: i think that is implemented in C underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be O(n^2) in both cases. My reasoning:

```
for idx,num in enumerate(hm3):
        for i in range(hm3[num]):
            l.append(num)
```

Outer loop: O(n)
Inner Loop: O(n) (Let's say inner loop runs for a max of k times)
append: O(1)
Total: n * k * O(1)=O(n*k)=O(n^2)

```
for n in hm3:
  l.extend( [n]*hm3[n])
```

Outer loop: O(n)
extend: O(n)
Total: O(n^2)

Let me know if my thinking is wrong.